# Выделение рамкой обязательной отметки чекбокса

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как добавить чекбоксу красную рамку (при нажатии на регистрацию), если он не отмечен?

```js
'use strict'

const email_wrap = document.getElementById('email_label')
const pass_wrap = document.getElementById('pass_label')
const checkbox_wrap = document.getElementById('label_checkbox')

const email = document.getElementById('email')
const pass = document.getElementById('password')
const chekbox = document.getElementById('checkbox')

function validateElement(val, condition, wrap) {
  wrap.classList.remove('error', 'error-novalue')
  wrap.classList.remove('error', 'error-notvalid')
  if (!val) {
    wrap.classList.add('error', 'error-novalue')
  } else if (!condition) {
    wrap.classList.add('error', 'error-notvalid')
  }
}

function validateEmail(email) {
  const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  validateElement(email.value, validateEmail(email.value), email_label)
  validateElement(pass.value, pass.value.length >= 8, pass_label)
  validateElement(chekbox.checked, true, label_checkbox)

  console.log({
    email: email.value,
    password: pass.value
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #1B2473;
  color: #787878;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 82px;
}

.form {
  width: 600px;
  height: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 25px 45px;
}

.form__title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.form__group {}


/*----------Проверить-----------*/

.form__label-input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
}


/*---------------------------------  */

.form__label-input span {
  display: block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.form__input {
  display: block;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 49px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px 0 6px 15px;
  outline: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

.form__input::placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 129%;
  color: #cccccc;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.form__label-checkbox {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form__checkbox {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.form__label-checkbox span {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.form__label-checkbox a {
  color: inherit;
}

.form__checkbox::after {
  content: '';
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  visibility: visible;
}

.form__checkbox:checked::after {
  content: '✓';
}

.form__btn {
  border: none;
  background: #1A226B;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  height: 58px;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*----------Media-----------*/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 38px;
  }
  .form__title {
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
  }
  .form__label-input span {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .form__label-input:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 19px;
  }
  .form__label-checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 64px;
  }
  .form__checkbox input {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
  .form__label-checkbox span {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .form__btn {
    width: 220px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}

.form__label-input,
.form__label-checkbox {
  position: relative;
}

.form__label-input::after,
.form__label-checkbox::after {
  content: '*';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -15px;
}

.form__label-checkbox::after {
  content: '*';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -15px;
}


/*----------ERRORS------------*/

.error.form__label-input::after,
.error.form__label-checkbox::after {
  color: #CB2424;
}

span.errors,
span.errors_valid {
  display: none;
  color: #CB2424;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}

.error.form__label-input span {
  color: #CB2424;
}

.error.form__label-input input,
.error.form__label-checkbox checkbox {
  border-color: #CB2424;
}

.error-novalue span.errors {
  display: block;
}

.error-notvalid span.errors_valid {
  display: block;
}

.error-novalue,
.error-notvalid {
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="wrapper">
    <form action="#" class="form">

      <h1 class="form__title">Регистрация</h1>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input" id="email_label">
          <span>Email</span>
          <input class="form__input" id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Введите Email">
          <span class="errors">Поле обязательно для заполнения</span>
          <span class="errors_valid">Email невалидный</span>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label for="" class="form__label-input" id="pass_label">
          <span>Пароль</span>
          <input class="form__input" id="password" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль"> 
          <span class="errors">Поле обязательно для заполнения</span>
          <span class="errors_valid">Пароль должен содержать как минимум 8 символов</span>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label-checkbox" id="label_checkbox">
          <input class="form__checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"> 
          <span>Я согласен c <a href="#">Правилами пользования приложением</a> </span>
          <span class="errors">Поле обязательно для заполнения</span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form__button-block">
        <button class="form__btn" id="btn" type="submit">Регистрация</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

  <script src="./script1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить этот кусок кода в конец вашего css файла

```
.error-novalue .form__checkbox::after,
.error-notvalid .form__checkbox::after {
  border-color: #CB2424;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)  Но не знаю как Вам поставить оценку за ответ)

Comment: @ИгорьТрубников, просто нажмите на стрелку "Ответ полезен". Рад, что помог